# Расположение JDialog в центре экрана

Tags: java, swing

Подскажите пожалуйста в приведенном коде левых верхний угол объекта JDialog помещен в центр экрана, мне необходимо, что бы в центре экрана был центр объекта

```
public class RaschetDialog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JDialog raschetDialog=new JDialog();
        raschetDialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        raschetDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        raschetDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        raschetDialog.setSize(600,400);
        raschetDialog.setVisible(true);
        raschetDialog.dispose();
        for (int i=0;i<1000;i++){
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменяйте местами - сначала задавайте размер, метод setLocationRelativeTo использует для расчета позиционирования размеры окна

```
 ...
 raschetDialog.setSize(600,400);
 raschetDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 ...
```